# environment module : Cannot initialize TCL

Tags: environment-variables, path, package-management

I am trying to create a python-2.7.10 module on a CentOS 6 cluster.  My simple `python-2.7.10` module file is :

```
#%Module1.0
prepend-path PATH /gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/bin 
prepend-path MANPATH /gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/share
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH /gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/lib
set-alias python /gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python
set-alias python2.7 /gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python
```

When I load the module, e.g.

```
module load python-2.7.10
```

python2.7 works fine. However, if I try to `module list` or `module avail` or `module unload python-2.7.10`

I get the error

```
init.c(556):ERROR:161: Cannot initialize TCL
```

However, if I try my `octave-4.0.0` module :

```
#%Module1.0
prepend-path PATH /gpfs0/export/opt/octave-4.0.0/bin 
prepend-path MANPATH /gpfs0/export/opt/octave-4.0.0/share
prepend-path LD_LIBRARY_PATH /gpfs0/export/opt/octave-4.0.0/lib
set-alias octave /gpfs0/export/opt/octave-4.0.0/bin/octave-4.0.0 
set-alias octave-gui /gpfs0/export/opt/octave-4.0.0/bin/octave-4.0.0 
set-alias octave-cli /gpfs0/export/opt/octave-4.0.0/bin/octave-cli-4.0.0
```

I can `module list`, `module avail` and `module unload octave-4.0.0` just fine.  Clearly, my `python-2.7.10` module has broken something.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=719785

Comment: Actually, you are correct.  This appears to be an issue with LD_LIBRARY_PATH getting pointed to a libtcl.o that doesn't play well with module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evidently, setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH is bad form as discussed [here](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206373/does-ld-library-path-really-cause-inconsistencies) and [here](http://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180).  So I changed my evil ways and did not set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and my problem was solved.

**EDIT** : It turns out that the root of this problem is a difference between the system `/usr/lib64/libtcl8.5.so` and anaconda's `/gpfs0/export/opt/anaconda-2.3.0/lib/libtcl8.5.so`.  Anaconda's tcl library is incompatible with the Modules package.  The solution stays the same, but if you need the anaconda libraries you need to handle those on a case by case basis.

Comment: So what's the alternative to setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH? This tutorial seems to suggest setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH: https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild/blob/master/docs/Installing-environment-modules-without-root-permissions.rst

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue and, using the suggestion from the link below, I  was able to correct the problem without unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  Basically, you disable the modulecmd's ability to use LD_LIBRARY_PATH for its execution; however, this change does not prevent  modulecmd from modifying the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.   The commands used are:
chown nobody:nobody modulecmd
chmod ug+s modulecmd

https://sourceforge.net/p/modules/mailman/message/27952351/